# repeating a special type of square wave over time

Tags: functions

I want to repeat the square wave shown in the picture over time after t=0.4 s, so the time period will be 0.4 s. And I want to repeat the same pattern over certain period of time, say 100 s. Anyone can help me with that?

[image]

Comment: I dont know the exact function, but one approach is to define the function, so it's a periodic function.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily use [`SquareWave`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SquareWave.html) for this:

```
With[{period = .4},
 Plot[SquareWave[x/period] SquareWave[{0, 1}, 2 x/period], {x, 0, 3}, 
  Exclusions -> None, PlotRange -> {-1.1, 1.1}]
 ]
```

[image: wave]

Comment: If you try to extend it over 10 seconds you will find a very weird shape at t=5.5 sec. Do you have any idea why's that?!

Comment: Yes, that's a common issue: the quick variations are overlooked by *Mathematica* - so you simply have to tell it to be more careful by adding the `Plot` option `PlotPoints -> 300` or some similarly large number.

Answer (score 2):

```
f = ListInterpolation[{1, 0, -1, 0, 1}, InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
       PeriodicInterpolation -> True][10 #] &;
Row[Plot[f@x, {x, 0, #}, Frame -> True,  PlotStyle -> Thick, Axes -> False, 
    ImageSize -> 350, PlotPoints -> 200] & /@ {1, 5, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, Clever... +1

Answer (score 1):

Here is my thinking.

- You need a periodic function of some kind to generate your periodicity. I decided to use the integer modulo function `Mod`, combined with a `Piecewise` function definition.
- Since you have four function values, i.e. $(1,0,-1,0)$, I used modulo $4$ division, which returns any one of $(0,1,2,3)$ for integer input.
- Since Mod wants integer input, I take the `IntegerPart` of the function argument.
- Finally, you want each period to be 0.1 units long: that's the origin of the $10\ x$ as the argument to `Mod`.

In short, here are the function definition and its plot:

```
periodicwave[x_] := Piecewise[{
   {1, Mod[IntegerPart[10 x], 4] == 0},
   {0, Mod[IntegerPart[10 x], 4] == 1},
   {-1, Mod[IntegerPart[10 x], 4] == 2},
   {0, Mod[IntegerPart[10 x], 4] == 3}
   }
 ]

Plot[
 periodicwave[x],
 {x, 0, 1},
 ExclusionsStyle -> Automatic
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: If you try to extend it over 10 seconds you will find a very weird shape at t=5.5 sec. Do you have any idea why's that?!

Comment: @AhmedMamdouh It is an artifact due to undersampling, i.e. to the number of points that the `Plot` function uses to construct the graph is too low to capture all the details of the function being plotted. You can force `Plot` to use more points by adding the option `PlotPoints -> 100` inside the `Plot` function: the weird shape will disappear. If you look at @kguler 's answer, `PlotPoints` is used there as well, presumably for the same reason.

Comment: Oh yeah, now it disappeared, thanks.